# How to update data in associated tables using Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

guys. I have two associated tables. "Users" and "Addresses". I'm trying to update the information in both tables.

I tried using the example below, but I get an error on the **updateAttributes** property

```
exports.update = (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  User.findOne({
    where: { id: id },
    include: [{ model: Addresses }],
  })
    .then(function (filter) {
      return filter.Addresses.updateAttributes({
        cep: 124124,
      });
    })
    .then(function () {
      // DONE! :)
    });
};
```

I get the following:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'updateAttributes')

Can you help me analyze how to solve this problem!

Is this the correct way to update data in associated models?

Comment: AFAIK `updateAttributes` is not a model's method at all. Did you want to use `update` instead of it? And it seems `findOne` did not find a user that's why JS could not read `updateAttributes`

Comment: Yes, I would like to use the update feature. As for the user, the id entered is a user that exists. I've also tried changing updateAttributes to update, but without success!

Comment: Just check `filter` content and show it in the task.